# Set default font-size in terminal

Tags: command-line, fonts

I just got myself a new 27 inch monitor and it is great. I can view things at a distance. However, when I launch the terminal, I cannot read things at a distance. And I want to increase the default font-size (and maybe font-family and font-weight too) to 3em. Where can I do this? I have not found anything related under Edit > Profile Preferences. The shell is Unity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under Edit -> Profile preferences is where it should be.

Maybe you didn't notice the checkbox?

[image]

Untick the `Use the system fixed width font` and you can change the size:

[image]

Comment: Could you also show how to do it from the command line? I am working with Vivid server, and do not have a desktop environment installed.

Comment: @Thomas That's quite a different question, as this is specifically for Gnome Terminal. Could Ask a new question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Thanks Tim! My mistake for skipping his last two sentences lol. I was able to figure this out shortly after posting my comment.

Comment: @Thomas In that case, consider posting a question and a self answer?! This will share the knowledge among the community, and you could find a different way as well!